# Development mode error after publishing ASP.NET MVC project on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to ASP.NET. I created an ASP.NET MVC project, but when I put it on IIS, I am getting an error:

[image]

I already changed Development to Production in `launchsettings.json` file.

I will appreciate if you have any idea on this.

Thanks,
Melina